# React-native 0.35 setState issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Unable to update the state from the database. console.log(db_name) returns the data. but unable to access it on render / state/ global.var.
How to make react to access local variables so that it can be used in the render jsx.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import axios from 'axios';

class Easycall extends Component {

constructor(props) {

 super(props);

 this.state = {name:"name",};

}

gettt(){

  axios.get('http://192.168.43.236/dbzx.php')

  .then(function (response) {

  let db_name = response.data.name ;

  this.setState({name:db_name});

});

}


render() {

  this.gettt();

  return (<Text>{this.state.name}</Text>);

  }


}


 AppRegistry.registerComponent('Easycall', () => Easycall);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change :

> ```
> gettt(){
>
>   axios.get('http://192.168.43.236/dbzx.php')
>
>   .then(function (response) {
>
>   let db_name = response.data.name ;
>
>   this.setState = ({name:db_name});
>
> });
>
> }
> ```

to:

```
gettt(){

  axios.get('http://192.168.43.236/dbzx.php')

  .then((response) => {

  let db_name = response.data.name ;

  this.setState = ({name:db_name});

});

}
```

Comment: @fkilaiwi: I edited your answer using some amount of guesswork. I assume this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class Easycall extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {name:"name"};
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.gett();
    }

    gettt(){
        axios.get('http://192.168.43.236/dbzx.php')
        .then(function (response) {
            let db_name = response.data.name ;
            this.setState({name:db_name});
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (<Text>{this.state.name}</Text>);
    }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Easycall', () => Easycall);
```

Comment: that was a mistake. fixed it. but it says undefined is not a function . evaluating setState . but i can console.log the data .the data is there

Comment: @MuneerPP: I edited your answer and took the liberty of removing a lot of excessive whitespace. The extra blank lines in the code are usually a result of incorrect formatting. If my edit was incorrect, then please use the [edit] link below your post to make improvements, or visit the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40072649/revisions) to rollback the post to another version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your methods in which you need access to `this`.

Avoid calling setState() in your render function. Instead add below lifecycle methods to your class above:

```
componentWillMount {
   this.gettt = this.gettt.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount {
   this.gettt()
}
```

You can now do **this**.setState() in gettt().

Comment: where do i put componentWillMount in the above code its es6 syntax . does it support it.